# Efficient implementation of segmented lines in C

Tags: c

below is a graph that shows 3 lines for 3 different settings. As you can see, these lines cannot be neatly described by simple math formulas, their coefficient changes abruptly.

I have thought of implementing it as a table in which the directional coefficients for the different segments are stored, but that kinda feels like an ugly method.

How would one implement this neatly?

[image: Plot of behaviour of 3 settings consisting of different segments]

Comment: These are continuous, but not differentiable functions :) and your idea of storing linear coefficients based on different inputs seems elegant enough (indeed, this seems to be the mathematical definition of the functions), what don't you like about it?

Comment: I fear you're going to be stuck with a table, and will have to iterate through it to find the right segment.

Comment: From the information you provide these functions are composed of segments, so what's wrong with a table? That's the way to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I guess indeed that the segments in a table are the way to go. I did not necessarily see something wrong with it, but I thought that perhaps there was a better trick for it.

Comment: It is possible to express this function as a linear combination of max(x-p[i],0) where p[i] are joint points

Comment: @tstanisl Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would solve it:

- I would store each line in a struct with a color and an array of points (x, y).
- Then I would create an SVG file or and EMF file from the structs, because both formats scale well.

The EMF file can be used in most office programs (and be converted to a bitmap if desired), whereas the SVG file can be used in browsers.

If you need to educate yourself, then search for "create emf in C" or read the SVG specification.